# How set value for all instance of component on page in Angular2?

Tags: angular, loops, components

I have following component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent {

ngOnInit()
{
  this.defaultCount = this.count;
}

  @Input()
  count: number;
  defaultCount: number;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }

  decrement() {
    if(this.count > 0)
    {
    this.count--;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
    }
  }

  reset()
  {
    this.count = this.defaultCount;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }
}
```

template:

```
<span>{{count}}</span>
<div>
  <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
  <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
  <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

In parrent component i'm using this component like below.
It is template:

```
<counter [count]="5" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
<counter [count]="10" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
<button (click)="resetAll()">Reset All</button>
```

and code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!';
      countChange(event) {
        //this.myCount = event;
      }

      resetAll(event)
      {

      }
    }
```

In `resetAll(event)` function, I want to set `[count]` for each instance of this component on the page, as it was before the events of increasing, decreasing or resetting.
How list only an instance of this component and reset the `[count]` property by calling reset function of each instance? I'm must add an same Id for each component and find by id  or i can find component by type? In my case the type is `CounterComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the `counters` values on a parent component, in your example, the AppComponent:

component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstCounter: number = 5;
  secondCounter: number = 10;

  resetAll(event) {
    this.firstCounter = 5;
    this.secondCounter = 10;
  }
}
```

html

```
<counter [count]="firstCounter" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
<counter [count]="secondCounter" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
<button (click)="resetAll()">Reset All</button>
```

---

### UPDATE

The best approach I could think to help you is the Observer/Observable pattern.

So I created an `CounterObserverService` that will yours `CounterComponent` will register themselves to it and then their state will be managed by the `Service`, take a look:

CounterComponent

```
import {
  CounterObservable,
  CounterObserverService
} from './counter-observer.service';
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  EventEmitter,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  template: `
    <span>{{ count }}</span>
    <div>
      <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
      <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
      <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  count: number;

  private counterObservable: CounterObservable;
  private counterSubscription: Subscription;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(
    private counterObserverService: CounterObserverService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counterObservable = this.counterObserverService.register(this.count);
    this.counterSubscription = this.counterObservable.currentCount.subscribe((counte) => {
      this.count = counte;
      this.change.emit(this.count);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.counterSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.counterObserverService.unregister(this.counterObservable);
  }

  increment() {
    this.updateCurrentCount(1);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.updateCurrentCount(-1);
  }

  reset() {
    this.counterObserverService.reset(this.counterObservable.id);
  }

  private updateCurrentCount(increment: number) {
    const newCount = this.count + increment;
    if (newCount > 0) {
      this.counterObservable.currentCount.next(newCount);
    }
  }

}
```

CounterObserverService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export interface CounterObservable {
  id: string;
  initialCount: number;
  currentCount: BehaviorSubject<number>;
}

@Injectable()
export class CounterObserverService {

  private counters: CounterObservable[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  register(initialCount: number): CounterObservable {
    const counterObservable = {
      id: uuid(),
      initialCount,
      currentCount: new BehaviorSubject<number>(initialCount)
    }
    this.counters.push(counterObservable);
    return counterObservable;
  }

  unregister(counterObservable: CounterObservable): void {
    const index = this.counters.indexOf(counterObservable);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.counters.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  reset(id: string): void {
    const counterObservable = this.counters.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (counterObservable) {
      counterObservable.currentCount.next(counterObservable.initialCount);
    }
  }

  resetAll() {
    this.counters.forEach((counterObservable) => {
      counterObservable.currentCount.next(counterObservable.initialCount);
    });
  }

}
```

*Don't forget to register this service in the `providers` array of your AppModule*

AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterObserverService } from './counter/counter-observer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <counter *ngFor="let counter of counters" [count]="counter"
    (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
  <button (click)="addCounter()">Add</button>
  <button (click)="removeCounter()">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="resetAll()">Reset All</button>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  counters = [1, 2, 3];

  constructor(
    private counterObserverService: CounterObserverService
  ) {}


  addCounter() {
    this.counters.push(this.counters.length + 1);
  }

  removeCounter() {
    this.counters.pop();
  }

  countChange(event) {}

  resetAll() {
    this.counterObserverService.resetAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an option but it does not quite fit if there are a lot of such components and they are added dynamically. Please look I'm changed code and question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use by @ViewChildren.
For your example:
adding in parent component

```
@ViewChildren(counterComponent) counters: QueryList<counterComponent>

this.counters.forEach(counterInstance => counterInstance.count=5);
```